# Cannot start MySQL server, Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

My database stoped working today and I can't figure out why, the only response it gives me is:

```
● mysqld.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysqld; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-08-16 17:31:24 UTC; 30s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 4680 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysqld start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 16 17:31:21 kdymsolucoes.dev.br systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Aug 16 17:31:24 kdymsolucoes.dev.br mysqld[4680]: Starting MySQL... * The server quit without updating PID file (/www/server/data/kdymsolucoes.dev.br.pid).
Aug 16 17:31:24 kdymsolucoes.dev.br systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 16 17:31:24 kdymsolucoes.dev.br systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 17:31:24 kdymsolucoes.dev.br systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
```

I have restarted the server, reinstalled it, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 16 17:31:24 kdymsolucoes.dev.br systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 17:31:24 kdymsolucoes.dev.br systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysqld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 1593 and the job result is failed.
Aug 16 17:31:58 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5471]: Invalid user jake from 113.57.170.50 port 37434
Aug 16 17:31:58 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5471]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Aug 16 17:31:58 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5471]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=113.57.170.50
Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5475]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5476]: (root) CMD (/root/-)
Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sendmail[5477]: 27GHW1nS005477: from=root, size=324, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202208161732.27GHW1nS005477@kdymsolucoes.d>Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sm-mta[5478]: 27GHW1Fv005478: from=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br>, size=600, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202208161732.27GHW1nS0>Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sendmail[5477]: 27GHW1nS005477: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30324, re>Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5475]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5471]: Failed password for invalid user jake from 113.57.170.50 port 37434 ssh2
Aug 16 17:32:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sm-mta[5479]: 27GHW1Fv005478: to=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br>, ctladdr=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xd>Aug 16 17:32:03 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5471]: Received disconnect from 113.57.170.50 port 37434:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 16 17:32:03 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5471]: Disconnected from invalid user jake 113.57.170.50 port 37434 [preauth]
Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5572]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5573]: (root) CMD (/root/-)
Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sendmail[5574]: 27GHX1g2005574: from=root, size=324, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202208161733.27GHX1g2005574@kdymsolucoes.d>Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sm-mta[5576]: 27GHX1kx005576: from=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br>, size=600, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202208161733.27GHX1g20>Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sendmail[5574]: 27GHX1g2005574: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30324, re>Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5572]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 17:33:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sm-mta[5577]: 27GHX1kx005576: to=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br>, ctladdr=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xd>Aug 16 17:33:14 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5586]: Invalid user server from 223.75.51.167 port 45114
Aug 16 17:33:14 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5586]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Aug 16 17:33:14 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5586]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=223.75.51.167
Aug 16 17:33:16 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5586]: Failed password for invalid user server from 223.75.51.167 port 45114 ssh2
Aug 16 17:33:16 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5586]: Received disconnect from 223.75.51.167 port 45114:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 16 17:33:16 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5586]: Disconnected from invalid user server 223.75.51.167 port 45114 [preauth]
Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5588]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5589]: (root) CMD (/root/-)
Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sendmail[5590]: 27GHY1sZ005590: from=root, size=324, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202208161734.27GHY1sZ005590@kdymsolucoes.d>Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sm-mta[5591]: 27GHY1WQ005591: from=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br>, size=600, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202208161734.27GHY1sZ0>Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sendmail[5590]: 27GHY1sZ005590: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30324, re>Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br CRON[5588]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 17:34:01 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sm-mta[5592]: 27GHY1WQ005591: to=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br>, ctladdr=<root@kdymsolucoes.dev.br> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xd>Aug 16 17:34:36 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5600]: Invalid user ubuntu from 223.75.51.167 port 17031
Aug 16 17:34:36 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5600]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Aug 16 17:34:36 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5600]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=223.75.51.167
Aug 16 17:34:37 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5600]: Failed password for invalid user ubuntu from 223.75.51.167 port 17031 ssh2
Aug 16 17:34:39 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5600]: Received disconnect from 223.75.51.167 port 17031:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Aug 16 17:34:39 kdymsolucoes.dev.br sshd[5600]: Disconnected from invalid user ubuntu 223.75.51.167 port 17031 [preauth]
```

It just gives me the same output from the status command.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You are getting "Invalid user jake" - it looks like this is a Unix user and not a MySQL user. Does this user exist on the box? What happens if you try to recreate it?

Comment: Is it a standalone box e.g. a VPS? Could you create a new server, install exactly the same version of MySQL on another box, and copy the data files into place on the new box?

Comment: @halfer I have tried copying /var/lib/mysql to another server but it doesn't work, is there another way I can copy this database without mysqldump?

Comment: It will work, you are just doing something wrong. The most likely problem is that your new version of the server is not the same as the old one. You can only do this trick if you are installing exactly the same version.

Comment: Incidentally, your getting advice here will be made harder with reports like "doesn't work". That is not a useful fault report. When you experience a problem, be as detailed as you can - explain how it did not work, with as much information as you can muster. That will reduce the number of conversational loops needed to get you to a working system.

Comment: @halfer I have copied the files from /var/lib/mysql and the tables and schemas didn't appeared in the other database, I haven't tried to install the exact same version, I'll try now

Comment: My database version installed is 5.7.37, but the only version I'm able to install on the other server is 5.7.39. I have copied all the files of /var/lib/mysql to this other server. I can see the schema names, but all of them returns zero tables inside. Do you think this minor version difference is causing this?

Comment: Possibly. It is true that you are normally bound to the version(s) of the server that your Linux distro contains. However, you could try installing the exact version via Docker.

Comment: I would also not give up on repairing the old box. Make sure you take a disk backup, and then try the suggestions I made about Unix users earlier.

Comment: @halfer I don't have any of these users in the database nor any application that connects using them, I don't know where they are coming from

Comment: Well, no, Unix users are not database users. But perhaps they are hack attempts from the internet.

Comment: Perhaps you could try starting your database via `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe` so you can see why it is not starting. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with a backup that I had from 8 days ago. I downloaded the files from `/var/lib/mysql` and copied to the backup that has a working mysql server. I had to solve several errors and permissions, but was able to solve them by checking `/var/log/mysql/errors.log` constantly.

Thanks @halfer to helping me find the way to do it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).